# No attachment path in json, join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, blob, attachment

Need some help..

I have user, offer and country model. The user has_one_attached :image.
Offer & User => has_and_belongs_to_many

Displaying all users grouped by country in controller:

```
offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
render json: offer.users.joins(:country).group_by { |t| t.country.name }
```

Serializer

```
class OfferSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

attributes :id, :name, :image

def image
 rails_blob_path(object.image, only_path: true) if object.image.attached?
end
```

I do get:

```
 {"country1": [
 {
 "id": 9,
 "country_id": 1,
 "online": true,
...
{
"id": 12,
"bundesland_id": 1,
 "online": true,
...
```

and i need to get additional:

```
"header_image": "/rails/active_storag...
```

But I don't get the user.blob path in the json!
Any idea?
Thanks for support!

Comment: What is the output you do get?

Comment: You say that the `User` has one attached but you are trying to get an `image` field from the `Offer`?

Comment: render json: offer.users. .. This query is in the offers_controller. I thought I also get the user.has_one_attached.  ..but no :-|
Any Idea where to join/include that attached relation?